# Setup so users can follow(bookmark) other users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created two different sets of coding that was suppose to allow a User to follow (bookmark) another User. For example User A follows User B, C, & D. User A goes to their favorites page and it lists all the users they're following (B,C & D). This would be a one way follow. The code I created did not perform the action of following a user, so I decided to follow the railstutorial Twitter following concept. I am getting a "uninitialized constant RelationshipsController". So something is wrong with the routes.

Can someone take a look and perhaps point out what is wrong?

*On a side note, this feels like a lot of coding for something so simple...even when I was doing it myself without following a tutorial. I simply just want Users to be able to bookmark another Users page url, have it saved to some Favorites page (essentially a Bookmark page) and give them the option to remove that bookmark. I would think a database wouldn't even be required for this.*

routes:

```
  resources :sessions,      only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :users do  
      get 'settings', on: :member  
  end
```

user model:

```
      has_many :notifications
      has_many :users, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
      has_many :followed_users, through: :relationships, source: :followed
      has_many :reverse_relationships, foreign_key: "followed_id", class_name: "Relationship", dependent: :destroy
      has_many :followers, through: :reverse_relationships, source: :follower

  def following?(other_user)
    relationships.find_by(followed_id: other_user.id)
  end

  def follow!(other_user)
    relationships.create!(followed_id: other_user.id)
  end

  def unfollow!(other_user)
    relationships.find_by(followed_id: other_user.id).destroy!
  end
```

Comment: I needed to add relationships_controller to get this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go this route:

```
resources :sessions,      only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
resources :users do  
  get 'settings', on: :member  
  post 'follow', on: :member 
  post 'unfollow, on: :member 
end
```

in your users controller:

```
def follow
  friend = User.find params[:user_id]
  current_user.follow! friend unless current_user.following? friend
  redirect_to friend
end

def unfollow
  friend = User.find params[:user_id]
  current_user.unfollow! friend
  redirect_to friend
end
```

and when displaying a user for which you want to follow/unfollow

```
<% if current_user.following? @user %>
  <%= link_to 'Bookmark', follow_user_path(user_id: @user.id), method: :post %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to 'Remove Bookmark', unfollow_user_path(user_id: @user.id), method: :post %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I used a combination of this answer and some additional code + added a relationships controller. Thank you for the help. I also finished the other two custom code I wrote for favorites and have it working, so if someone needs a custom solution just let me know and I will post my code.

Answer (score 2):

Think about it like Relationship is a join table between a many-to-many association (i.e. a user can follow many people and a user can be followed by many people). You shouldn't need Relationship routes. Remove `resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]`. Also, make sure you've migrated in a Relationship table like:

```
class CreateRelationships < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :relationships do |t|
      t.integer  "follower_id"
      t.integer  "followed_id"
    end
  end
  def self.down
    drop_table :relationships
  end
end
```

and created a Relationship model like:

```
class Relationship <ActiveRecord::Base            
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
end
```